# Changing variable within while loop

Tags: php

Instead of having code like the following:

```
if ( $Boss1 ==1)
            {
                $Boss1_holder = $tick;
            }

            else if ( $Boss1 ==0)
            {
                $Boss1_holder = $cross;
            }



            if ( $Boss2 ==1)
            {
                $Boss2_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss2 ==0)
            {
                $Boss2_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss3 ==1)
            {
                $Boss3_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss3 ==0)
            {
                $Boss3_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss4 ==1)
            {
                $Boss4_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss4 ==0)
            {
                $Boss4_holder = $cross;
            }
```

Can i instead do something like this:

```
                $i = 1;
            while ($i <= 4) 
            {
                if ( $Boss[$i] ==1)
                {
                    $boss_holder[$i] = $tick;
                }

                else if ( $Boss[$i] ==0)
                {
                    $boss_holder[$i] = $cross;
                }

            }
```

I'm not entirely sure how to do it. At the moment if only have 4 sets of if else statements but my program later would require about 30 of them and i would rather having something like my second block that will reduce the amount of lines required. Am i on the right track. I think the $boss_holder[$i] part is incorrect as [i] would be part of an array? however i dont know how to write this correctly. I have looked on the php manual page but a lot of the examples are some what complex and go above the scope i need.

To clarify if i have explanined this poorly. I am trying to add a value onto the end of the variable $boss_holder that increments with the while loop counter

```
    $Boss1_holder = '';
$Boss2_holder = '';
$Boss3_holder = '';
$Boss4_holder = '';
$Boss5_holder = '';
$Boss6_holder = '';
$Boss7_holder = '';
$Boss8_holder = '';
$Boss9_holder = '';
$Boss10_holder = '';
$Boss11_holder = '';
$Boss12_holder = '';
$Boss13_holder = '';
$Boss14_holder = '';
$Boss15_holder = '';
$completed1 = 0;
$completed2 = 0;
$completed3 = 0;
$counter = 0;
$tick ='&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/tick.png">';
$cross ='&nbsp;<img src="/styles/subsilver2/theme/images/soap/cross.png">';
```

class checks 
{

```
private $addthemup1;
private $addthemup2;
private $addthemup3;

public function checkBosses($Boss1, $Boss2, $Boss3, $Boss4, $Boss5, $Boss6, $Boss7, $Boss8, $Boss9, $Boss10, $Boss11, $Boss12, $Boss13, $Boss14, $Boss15)
{
    global  $tick, $cross, $completed1, $completed2, $completed3, $Boss1_holder, $Boss2_holder, $Boss3_holder, $Boss4_holder, $Boss5_holder, $Boss6_holder, $Boss7_holder, $Boss8_holder, $Boss9_holder, $Boss10_holder, $Boss11_holder, $Boss12_holder, $Boss13_holder, $Boss14_holder, $Boss15_holder;

    $addthemup1 = $Boss1 + $Boss2 + $Boss3 + $Boss4 + $Boss5;
    $addthemup2 = $Boss6 + $Boss7 + $Boss8 + $Boss9 + $Boss10;
    $addthemup3 = $Boss11 + $Boss12 + $Boss13 + $Boss14 + $Boss15;

    switch ($addthemup1)
            {
                case "5":
                $completed1 = $tick;
                break;

                case "4":
                $completed1 ='4/5';
                break;  

                case "3":
                $completed1 ='3/5';
                break;  

                case "2":
                $completed1 ='2/5';
                break;

                case "1":
                $completed1 ='1/5';
                break;  

                case "0":
                $completed1 ='0/5';
                break;  
            }
    switch ($addthemup2)
            {
                case "5":
                $completed2 = $tick;
                break;

                case "4":
                $completed2 ='4/5';
                break;  

                case "3":
                $completed2 ='3/5';
                break;  

                case "2":
                $completed2 ='2/5';
                break;

                case "1":
                $completed2 ='1/5';
                break;  

                case "0":
                $completed2 ='0/5';
                break;  
            }
    switch ($addthemup3)
            {
                case "5":
                $completed3 = $tick;
                break;

                case "4":
                $completed3 ='4/5';
                break;  

                case "3":
                $completed3 ='3/5';
                break;  

                case "2":
                $completed3 ='2/5';
                break;

                case "1":
                $completed3 ='1/5';
                break;  

                case "0":
                $completed3 ='0/5';
                break;  
            }




            if ( $Boss1 ==1)
            {
                $Boss1_holder = $tick;
            }

            else if ( $Boss1 ==0)
            {
                $Boss1_holder = $cross;
            }



            if ( $Boss2 ==1)
            {
                $Boss2_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss2 ==0)
            {
                $Boss2_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss3 ==1)
            {
                $Boss3_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss3 ==0)
            {
                $Boss3_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss4 ==1)
            {
                $Boss4_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss4 ==0)
            {
                $Boss4_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss5 ==1)
            {
                $Boss5_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss5 ==0)
            {
                $Boss5_holder = $cross;
            }

            if ( $Boss6 ==1)
            {
                $Boss6_holder = $tick;
            }

            else if ( $Boss6 ==0)
            {
                $Boss6_holder = $cross;
            }

            if ( $Boss7 ==1)
            {
                $Boss7_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss7 ==0)
            {
                $Boss7_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss8 ==1)
            {
                $Boss8_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss8 ==0)
            {
                $Boss8_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss9 ==1)
            {
                $Boss9_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss9 ==0)
            {
                $Boss9_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss10 ==1)
            {
                $Boss10_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss10 ==0)
            {
                $Boss10_holder = $cross;
            }

            if ( $Boss11 ==1)
            {
                $Boss11_holder = $tick;
            }

            else if ( $Boss11 ==0)
            {
                $Boss11_holder = $cross;
            }



            if ( $Boss12 ==1)
            {
                $Boss12_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss12 ==0)
            {
                $Boss12_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss13 ==1)
            {
                $Boss13_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss13 ==0)
            {
                $Boss13_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss14 ==1)
            {
                $Boss14_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss14 ==0)
            {
                $Boss14_holder = $cross;
            }


            if ( $Boss15 ==1)
            {
                $Boss15_holder = $tick;
            }
            else if ( $Boss15 ==0)
            {
                $Boss15_holder = $cross;
            }


}
```

}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `raid_progression`';

```
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);

  while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
  {      
            $counter = $counter+1;

            $checker1 = new checks();   
            $checkResult1 = $checker1-> checkBosses($row['kp_em_no_bonethr'], $row['kp_em_no_foreman'], $row['kp_em_no_heavyfab'], $row['kp_em_no_jargsor'], $row['kp_em_no_kragga'],$row['kp_em_ha_bonethr'], $row['kp_em_ha_foreman'], $row['kp_em_ha_heavyfab'], $row['kp_em_ha_jargsor'], $row['kp_em_ha_kragga'],$row['kp_em_kn_bonethr'], $row['kp_em_kn_foreman'], $row['kp_em_kn_heavyfab'], $row['kp_em_kn_jargsor'], $row['kp_em_kn_kragga']);



            $template->assign_block_vars('raid_op', array(
            'VAR0' => $counter,
            'VAR1' => $row['guild_name'],
            'VAR2' => $row['guild_website'],
            'VAR3' => $row['server_name'],
            'VAR4' => $row['server_region'],
            'VAR5' => $row['faction_name'],
            'VAR6' => $completed1,
            'VAR7' => $Boss1_holder,
            'VAR8' => $Boss2_holder,
            'VAR9' => $Boss3_holder,
            'VAR10' => $Boss4_holder,
            'VAR11' => $Boss5_holder,
            'VAR12' => $Boss6_holder,
            'VAR13' => $Boss7_holder,
            'VAR14' => $Boss8_holder,
            'VAR15' => $Boss9_holder,
            'VAR16' => $Boss10_holder,
            'VAR17' => $Boss11_holder,
            'VAR18' => $Boss12_holder,
            'VAR19' => $Boss13_holder,
            'VAR20' => $Boss14_holder,
            'VAR21' => $Boss15_holder,
            'VAR22' => $completed2,
            'VAR23' => $completed3,
            ));






  }

  $db->sql_freeresult($result);
```

Comment: Will the Bosses only be holding 'ticks' and 'crosses'?

Comment: Yes.  $tick ='&nbsp;<img src="tick.png">';
 $cross ='&nbsp;<img src="cross.png">';

Comment: I have updated at the bottom my description as it may have been poorly explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways to do it...

```
$boss = new array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach($boss as $value){
    switch($value){
         case 1: 
            //do something
         break;
         case 2: 
            //something else;
         break;
    }
}
```

Would probably be how I wrote it.

Edit: If you're looking for clean code, you can do something like this:

**bosshandler.php:**

```
function doSomethingWithBoss($value){
    switch($value){
         case 1: 
            return "boss equals 1";
         break;
         case 2: 
            return "boss equals 2";
         break;
    }
}
```

**Your script page:**

```
include bosshandler.php;
$boss = new array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach($boss as $value){
    echo doSomethingWithBoss($value);
}
```

*Ok, trying again. I think I see what you're asking now:*

You want to assign a variable so that your arrays match up. If you're in `$boss[1]` you want to assign something to `$boss_holder['1']`, is that correct? If so, you don't want to use a foreach array, as it can be somewhat unpredictable with arrays and the order in which it parses them.

Instead, let's use a `for()` loop, like so:

```
$boss = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$boss_holder = new Array(); //empty
$length = count($boss);
//iterate through boss
for($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++){
    if($boss[$i] == 1){
        $boss_holder[$i] = $tick;
    }elseif($boss[$i] == 2){
        $boss_holder[$i] = $cross;
    }
}
```

**Edit again to reflect your full code:**

Use arrays. Refactor your code so that it uses arrays. If for some reason you absolutely cannot or will not use arrays, you can use PHP's [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to accomplish what you're looking for. It would look something like this:

```
var $boss1_holder, $boss2_holder, $boss3_holder;
for($i=1; $i> 4; $i++){
    $variableName = 'boss' . $i . '_holder';
    $$variableName = 1;
}
echo $boss2_holder; //returns 2
```

Comment: That's how I would do it too.

Comment: i'd prefer to keep away from this as  i would have alot of case statements and im trying to reduce the code count

Comment: I find case statements to be more readable than a ton of if/else blocks. If you want to make your code look cleaner, you can put the code inside a function, and then call the function inside the foreach. I'll edit to give you an example of that.

Comment: I have updated at the bottom my description as it may have been poorly explained

Comment: @RyanWalkowski Check out my latest answer... i think I understand the question now, let me know if that helps?

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski I have included the entire code so you can see it. Im not actually using an array again i fear i may have explained it pretty poorly up top

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski Took me a while to really understand what you were trying to show here. I had to lookup part of it. But slightly modified it works great. Thanks for your help. PS Cool last name :)

Comment: You really should be using arrays, but if not... i think variable variables can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
$bosses = new array(1, 2, 1, 1, 2);
$boss_holders = new array()

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($boss); $i++) {
    // if bosses[i] equals 1, we make the current boss_holder equal a $tick
    if($bosses[i] == 1) 
        array_push($boss_holders, $tick);

    // if the current boss doesn't equal 1 then it must equal 2
    // so we add a $cross instead
    else
        array_push($boss_holders, $cross);
}
```

*Please note: The above code is untested and may contain errors, as my PHP's a little (well, a lot) rusty.*

What it does is creates a new array of bosses (you can set this value to whatever numbers you have for your bosses), and an empty array called $boss_holders. We then go through the array of bosses and if the current Boss equals 1, then we add a $tick. Otherwise, the current Boss equals 2, so we'll add a $cross.

When the for loop has finished running, what you'll have is an array of `boss_holders` that reflects the values of the bosses. If boss1 = 1, boss2 = 2, and boss3 = 1, the array boss_holders will look like this: `[$tick, $cross, $tick]`, and so on. When you need to access `boss_holder_2`'s value, for instance, you get that value by accessing the `boss_holder` array like this: `boss_holders[2]`.

Does that make sense? Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

From the first example:

```
if ($i == 0) {
  echo "i equals 0";
} elseif ($i == 1) {
  echo "i equals 1";
} elseif ($i == 2) {
  echo "i equals 2";
}
```

Is the same like:

```
switch ($i) {
  case 0:
    echo "i equals 0";
    break;
  case 1:
    echo "i equals 1";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "i equals 2";
    break;
}
```

but looks much cleaner.

Comment: That isn't what he's doing though.

Comment: That's suboptimal. A while loop is probably the best way to go in this case, although I suppose that depends on the OP's response to my comment on his question.

Comment: Yeah, i fear my written explanation may have not been entirely clear. I am trying to give the variable $boss_holder a number on the end of it that would go up instead with the while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
Have you tried using variable variables? The first script will print out the variables created, while the second demonstrates that a variable can be defined or determined by modifying the "if" statement.  Maybe this will be helpful for your situation. `
```

` ";
    $i++;
    }
    ?>

```
<?php
$i=1;
$boss4_holder=true;

while($i<10){
    $q="boss".$i."_holder";

    if ($$q==true){
         echo "true";
    }
$i++;
}
?>
```